# Displaying hex from Serial using pi4j

Tags: java, serial-port, hex, raspberry-pi

I'm using a raspberry pi to communicate with an RFID reader, I have used the PI4J library to receive string data, but the reader outputs hex. So far I have converted the string data to hex format using:

```
import org.apache.commons.codec.binary.Hex;
```

To split up the hex into groups of two I have used:

```
java.util.Arrays.toString
```

so the code in whole:

```
        // create and register the serial data listener
    serial.addListener(new SerialDataListener() {
        @Override
        public void dataReceived(SerialDataEvent event) {


            String str = event.getData(); //create string of data received
            //change string to hex representation && split into groups of two
            System.out.println(java.util.Arrays.toString(Hex.encodeHexString(str.getBytes()).split("(?<=\\G..)")));
        }            
    });
```

I am currently using an old pc running advanced serial port Terminal to send commands to the raspberry pi, emulating what will be received from the RFID reader. The code which I am sending to the pi and want to display is

> 'A0 03 82 00 DB'

But the pi displays

> '[c2, a0, 03, c2, 82, 00, c3, 9b]'

most of the data is there, but is split / missing some of the hex.
Another example of code i will be receiving:

> 'e0 10 82 00 01 00 00 00 02 04 09 02 64 12 34 57 e9 92'

Displays as:

> [c3, a0, 10, c2, 82, 00, 01, 00, 00, 00, 02, 04, 09, 02, 64, 12, 34, 57, c3, a9, c2, 92]

this time the first byte (e0) is missing but the last (92) is received. would anybody have any suggestions on what is going on? or how to resolve this?

Thanks in advance!